# Changing User Profile Sync OU

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user

A consultant came and created the sync connection with everything selected (he selected all OU from the forest). Now I have 10,000 + user profiles.

I unchecked all the OU and selected only one OU "Location" where we only have active users (and no other accounts like admin or service accounts, etc.).

I re-ran the full sync and the number reduced to 5000 + profiles. However, I still see service accounts and admin accounts which are in completely another OU.

What are my options to clean this mess? Right now when users do people search they see some users twice (regular account and his/her admin account). Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will see service accounts as they log into SharePoint. These are profiles disconnected from Active Directory.